# How to display the array items into different div's while iterating?

Tags: javascript

While iterating an array I would like to display first two arrays item into first DIV and second two array items into second Div and so on. I have achieved my result partially, but still, I believe this is not correct. How do I achieve this?

I would like to display following arrays items under each div's as below:

**First List:**
Pencil, 200
Rubber, 250
**Second List**
Sharpner, 300
Pen, 400

**Third List**
Paint, 500
Box, 50

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="best order1" id="one">
    <h1>First List</h1>

  </div>
  <div class="best order2" id="two">
    <h1>Second List </h1>

  </div>
  <div class="best order3" id="three">
    <h1>Third List</h1>

  </div>
  <input type="button" value="List" onclick="myArray();">

</div>
```

Below is my function;

```
function myArray() {

  var arr1 = [];
  arr1 = [{
      "Item": "Pencil",
      "Quantity": 200
    },
    {
      "Item": "Rubber",
      "Quantity": 250
    },
    {
      "Item": "Sharpner",
      "Quantity": 300
    },
    {
      "Item": "Pen",
      "Quantity": 400
    },
    {
      "Item": "Paint",
      "Quantity": 500
    },
    {
      "Item": "Box",
      "Quantity": 50
    }
  ];

  var portion = arr1.length / 2;

  for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    //alert(arr1[i].Item+','+arr1[i].Quantity );
    if (i <= portion) {
      document.getElementById('one').innerHTML += arr1[i].Item + ',' + arr1[i].Quantity + '<br>';

    } else {
      document.getElementById('two').innerHTML += arr1[i].Item + ',' + arr1[i].Quantity + '<br>';

    }

  }

}
```

This is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scrumvisualize/9d2buj47/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions is to add another one nested loop to control the portion of items, and this way you don't need `if` checks:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < portion; j++) {
    document.getElementById('wrapper-'+i).innerHTML += arr1[i*portion+j].Item + ',' + arr1[i*portion+j].Quantity + '<br>';
  }
}
```

I have also added `id`s like `wrapper-[number]` to get access to DOM elements from loop much easier.

Here is [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3n2138rp/)

And the snippet:

```js
function myArray() {

  var arr1 = [];
  arr1 = [{
      "Item": "Pencil",
      "Quantity": 200
    },
    {
      "Item": "Rubber",
      "Quantity": 250
    },
    {
      "Item": "Sharpner",
      "Quantity": 300
    },
    {
      "Item": "Pen",
      "Quantity": 400
    },
    {
      "Item": "Paint",
      "Quantity": 500
    },
    {
      "Item": "Box",
      "Quantity": 50
    }
  ];

  var portion = 2;

  for (i = 0; i < arr1.length / portion; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < portion; j++) {
      document.getElementById('wrapper-'+i).innerHTML += arr1[i*portion+j].Item + ',' + arr1[i*portion+j].Quantity + '<br>';
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="best order1" id="wrapper-0">
    <h1>First List</h1>

  </div>
  <div class="best order2" id="wrapper-1">
    <h1>Second List </h1>

  </div>
  <div class="best order3" id="wrapper-2">
    <h1>Third List</h1>

  </div>
  <input type="button" value="List" onclick="myArray();">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is. Declare number of sections. `portion` is a variable that will decide number of sections you want to display the data for.  To make it dynamic (in future if you need to change number of sections and if you've more even number of records).  And you can do all that within a single loop with basic maths.

**Step1** : Get all the section ids by `document.querySelectorAll(".best").forEach(e=>   ids.push(e.getAttribute("id")) )`

**Step2** : Declare number of Portions by `var portion = arr1.length / 4;`

**Step3** : Loop through array and append data as `html` as

```
 var counter = -1;
arr1.map((e,i)=> {
     if(i%portion == 0)
     counter++;
      document.getElementById(ids[counter]).innerHTML += e.Item +","+e.Quantity+"</br>"

} )
```

Here is the snippet

```js
function myArray() {

  var arr1 = [];
  arr1 = [{
      "Item": "Pencil",
      "Quantity": 200
    },
    {
      "Item": "Rubber",
      "Quantity": 250
    },
    {
      "Item": "Sharpner",
      "Quantity": 300
    },
    {
      "Item": "Pen",
      "Quantity": 400
    },
    {
      "Item": "Paint",
      "Quantity": 500
    },
    {
      "Item": "Box",
      "Quantity": 50
    },
     {
      "Item": "ABC",
      "Quantity": 123
    },
    {
      "Item": "XYZ",
      "Quantity": 123
    }
  ];

  var portion = arr1.length / 4;
  var ids = [];
  document.querySelectorAll(".best").forEach(e=>   ids.push(e.getAttribute("id")) )
   var counter = -1;
    arr1.map((e,i)=> {
         if(i%portion == 0)
         counter++;
          document.getElementById(ids[counter]).innerHTML += e.Item +","+e.Quantity+"</br>"
    
    } )

 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="best order1" id="one">
    <h1>First List</h1>

  </div>
  <div class="best order2" id="two">
    <h1>Second List </h1>

  </div>
  <div class="best order3" id="three">
    <h1>Third List</h1>

  </div>
  <div class="best order3" id="four">
    <h1>Forth List</h1>

  </div>
  <input type="button" value="List" onclick="myArray();">

</div>
```

Ps.  You'll have to be wise to decide sections based on the number of records you've in your array.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr1 = [{
  "Item": "Pencil",
  "Quantity": 200
},
{
  "Item": "Rubber",
  "Quantity": 250
},
{
  "Item": "Sharpner",
  "Quantity": 300
},
{
  "Item": "Pen",
  "Quantity": 400
},
{
  "Item": "Paint",
  "Quantity": 500
},
{
  "Item": "Box",
  "Quantity": 50
}];

let listNumber = 1;

const template = arr1.reduce((template, item, index) => {

  if (index % 2 === 0) {
    return template +=
    `<div class="best order1" id="one">
      <h1>List ${listNumber++}</h1>
      ${item.Item}, ${item.Quantity} </br>
    `;
  }

  return  template +=
    `  ${item.Item}, ${item.Quantity}
    </div>`;

}, '')

const resultHTML =
`<div class="container">
  ${template}
</div></br>`;

function list(){
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = resultHTML;
}

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = list;
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='content'></div>
    <input type="button" id='btn' value="List">
  </body>
</html>
```

I would use reduce to create the HTML dynamically:

```
let listNumber = 1;

const template = arr1.reduce((template, item, index) => {

  if (index % 2 === 0) {
    return template +=
    `<div class="best order1" id="one">
      <h1>List ${listNumber++}</h1>
      ${item.Item}, ${item.Quantity}
    `;
  }

  return template +=
    `  ${item.Item}, ${item.Quantity}
    </div>`;

}, '');
```

If you don't use es6, you can just concatenate the strings in the old way.